# Google login authorization error in android

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-signin

I am pretty sure I missed something in Firebase API Console when doing these auth steps. But I did all necessary steps and already got the google_services.json with the key to use in the application. But still don't know when I am trying to log in, it's showing me the account page and when I select the one from them! bang

The error page is showing the title `Authorization Error` and then.

Error401:disabled_client

This app is not yet configured to make OAuth request. To do that, set up the app's OAuth consent screen in the Google cloud console.

Did anyone face this issue ever?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24686567/google-oauth-authentication-suddenly-fails-and-issues-disabled-client

Comment: @mzeus.bolt Thanks for the link. for me i have still not uploaded my app in play store

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your app is on FireBase 
Go to fireBase console open your project under 'Developer' select 'Authentication' choose 'singIn' Methods from the authentication window and enable 'Google'

Comment: I'm working on an iOS app, not Android, and the Firebase > developer > authentication > signIn > Google dialog box said that only Android apps need to enable this parameter, however my iPad app would not work without enabling this

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the login method from Firebase Console.

Comment: An explanation of how to do this would be helpful as well.

Comment: agree with @scopchanov, that's a poor explanation